# Scroll website automatically to the right on iPad (to hide menu on the left)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Our website has a menu of 200px on the left side that is quite useful, but takes too much space on smaller devices like the iPad. So it would be nice to automatically scroll the website 200px horizontally to the right on the iPad.

I tried similar solutions using `@media (max-width: ????px) { .. }` CSS and hiding/showing the menu and letting it display using a button, but this isn't as elegant. Maybe there is a much simpler solution in jQuery?

To be more clear: I **want** the menu to be accessible all the time, so if I want to use it, I can simply scroll to the left, but in any other case it doesn't fill my screen.

Thanks a lot for help,
Josh

Comment: Why not just hide the menu using a media query and display none?

Comment: Based on your edit just use a javascript scrollTo when the page loads

Comment: Okay let's make this easier... stop trying to "hide it by scrolling" and hide it with a button to unhide it. That's how mobile menus work.

Comment: @ Steven: thank you, we had a solution like this a bit earlier already. Maybe you are right, at least Facebook has it that way, and I guess they know what they're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Moral of the story is you can't move a webpage 200px's over using CSS. You can use a javascript media query solution and do it. But that would be massively pointless since really you are just trying to hide the menu and there would be a period where the menu is shown then the page shifts which would be terrible.

So use CSS media queries and hide the menu.

Comment: I updated my question, I'm sorry I forgot this important information before.

Answer (score 2):

The following will hide the #menu div if the device width is between 768 and 1024px (iPad size, according to my [source](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/))

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width : 768px) 
  and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

  #menu {
    display: none;
  }

}
```

Comment: I updated my question, I'm sorry I forgot this important information before.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following jQuery code which seems to work:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     window.scrollTo(228,0);
  });
```